# Web Scraping: Taking a lot of time

Tags: python, web-scraping

My code below is just a piece and this is where it takes so much time. It works but it takes really long time and I have no idea what to do.

Say I have a list:

```py
ticker=['a','b','c','d','e','h','i','j','k','e']
```

which I get it from another url

Below is where it takes really really long time. I am sure it is because it gets 10 different urls and find the right pieces.. but how can I make it faster? is that even possible? It took over **3 mins.** It has to be within 10-15 secs..

```py
all_data=[]
for tick in ticker:
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tick+"?p="+tick+"&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1")
    yahoo =requests.get(url)
    access2 = BeautifulSoup(yahoo.text,'html.parser')
    rows = access2.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: You should time each piece and see how long each step takes. And report back

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and likely off-topic. Have you done any benchmarking or profiling? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck here is the Request/Response time. Each time you make a request, your program has to wait some time to get the response. This time is almost negligible for one request but it can add up to a significant amount when 10 requests are made.

To solve this problem, you can utilize `multi-threading`. You can make 10 threads - 1 for each request - and the total execution time will be significantly reduced! Here's a very good article on [Threading in Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will speed up the web scraping. It uses `multi-threading` as suggested by @Moosa.

```
ticker = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'e']

result = []

def fetch(tick):
    url = ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+tick+"?p="+tick+"&.tsrc=fin-srch-v1")
    yahoo = requests.get(url)
    access2 = BeautifulSoup(yahoo.text,'html.parser')
    rows = access2.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')
    result.append(rows)

def executor():
    threads = []
    for tick in ticker:
        t = Thread(target=fetch, args=(tick,))  # Create a new thread
        t.start()  # Execute the target of the thread - fetch
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()  # Wait for the child thread to complete

    return result

rows = executor()

for row in rows:
    ..... remaining code
```

Comment: Thank you, @Shiva and @Moosa But I used to use `rows` to `for each_row in rows` ... now when I try to use `result` instead of `rows`, it is blank... how do I get the result so I can loop through to find the data I need?

Comment: thank you for your prompt edition, but do you think if there is a way to make it quicker..? it now takes me 45 sec, which is a huge progress. And I was hoping to know if it can be within 10-15sec.

Comment: Also, I changed your `t = Tread(target ...` to `t = threading.Thread(target...` and it worked. how  could that be different? I used python jupyter

Comment: Your `import` statement is `import threading` whereas I used `from threading import Thread`.

Comment: Measure how much time it takes to  execute `yahoo = requests.get(url)`. If it's a large value, it means you internet connection is slow. If not, as suggested in the comments, profile your code and do the required optimisations. You may also look into https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks, Shiva. So I have tested.. and apparently `yahoo = requests.get(url)` took only 13sec. And I have noticed that once I add `access2 = BeautifulSoup(yahoo.text,'html.parser')` `rows = access2.find_all('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr')` is where it takes 49 sec. Do you still think multiprocessing may help..?  I really appreciate your help on this. Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, most probably. As per your profiling, it seems apart from fetching data, parsing and finding the elements inside the html is also taking considerable amount of time. Multiprocessing speeds up cpu bound operations such as parsing and searching. Multi-threading is useful for i/o bound operations such as fetching external data but have no(or sometimes negative) effect on overall execution time.